# Get next week of year in Java with java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I'd like to have a function which returns the next week and year given a week and year.  It looks something like:

```
public static int[] getNextWeek(int year, int week) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // I'm Locale.US and TimeZone "America/New_York"
    c.clear();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);

    c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

    return new int[] {c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)}
}
```

This sometimes does not work around year boundaries.  It seems to depend on what day you invoke it and for what parameters you use!  For example, if I invoke it with year 2012 and week 52 then I expect the result to be year 2013 and week 1.  If you invoke it today (Tuesday July 17 2012) it works.  If you set the day of week to yesterday it does not; and oddly results in year 2012 week 1.  Weird.  What is going on?  It appears to relate to the day of the week because it doesn't work if invoked with SUNDAY or MONDAY, which are the last two days of 2012!  If I set the day of the week to the last day of the week the function seems to work;  before calling Calendar.add() I do:

```
    // Must set to last day of week; initially set to first day due to API
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // SUNDAY
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); // Must roll forward not backwards
```

There doesn't seem to be any weirdness like this if I create a getPreviousWeek method.  Is this a java.util.Calendar bug?  Next time I guess I'll use Joda time!

Comment: Actually, this problem exists for the getPreviousWeek as well.  The getPreviousWeek implementation is the same as getNextWeek except instead of adding positive one week, add negative one week.  The fix of setting the DAY_OF_WEEK to the last day of the week seems to work with the getPreviousWeek as well.  The test case to show this is necessary is use year=2014 and week=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I'm going to assume this really is a bug.  I've filled a bug report with Oracle here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7197761

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the fact that ISO8601 week algorithm considers the first week of the year to be the one that has at least 4 days fall within that year?

So if the Jan 1 is on thurdsay, that week is actually considered week 52 of the previous year, not week one of the current year.

You might want to at least consider joda-time for this kind of calculation, as it has proper handling of the ISO standard.

```
    LocalDate ld = new LocalDate();
    ld = ld.withWeekOfWeekyear(29);
    ld = ld.withWeekyear(2012);

    System.out.println(ld.getWeekOfWeekyear());
    System.out.println(ld.getWeekyear());

    // 29
    // 2012


    System.out.println(ld.plusWeeks(1).getWeekOfWeekyear());
    System.out.println(ld.plusWeeks(1).getWeekyear());
    // 30
    // 2012
```

And this will work across year boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ISO8601.  If I wanted to be compliant with that I think java.util.Calendar is capable of supporting it and would just need to call Calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4).  I think in my locale (US) the default is 1.  I'm aware of Joda time and might use it next time, but don't really want to add another dependency to my project for a simple "getNextWeek" calculation even if the implementation is weird in java.util.Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Just do an explicit check to see if there's a rollover.

```
return new int[] {c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 1 ? c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1 :
    c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)};
```

As far as I can tell, the reason why `WEEK_OF_YEAR` doesn't add correctly is because it's not an actual property of `Calendar` like `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, or `YEAR`. It's a derived property like `WEEK_OF_MONTH`. One way to get around this is to use `c.add(Calendar.DAY, 7)` to add exactly 7 days instead of incrementing `WEEK_OF_YEAR`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense; you can't assume that if the week of the year is one then you automatically add one to the year; also you are returning an int array with one element in the 'if' and an int array with two elements in the 'else'.

Comment: if the week is one, you've rolled over, and it doesn't return an array with two elements in the else. it evaluates `c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 1` and either returns  `c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1` or `c.get(Calendar.YEAR)` in the first position.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Your code is extremely hard to read due to piling it all in one line.  Yes, it does seem to accomplish the same thing as setting the day of the week to the last day of the week, but in a harder to read way.  But you haven't actually answered my question.  Why does Calendar behave this way?

Comment: I appreciate your interest so I upvoted.  However, there is no Calendar.DAY and using Calendar.DATE still results in the wrong answer.  Also I noticed your initial code section (check for rollover) won't work for function parameters year=2011 and week=53 because the values are correctly transformed to 2012 week 1 BEFORE they reach your code in this case so your code will increment the year incorrectly.

Comment: @Ryan c.add(Calendar.Minute, 604800)?

Comment: You mean c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10080)?  That doesn't work either.  It probably fails for the same reason c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1) does.